# How to setup Salesforce Mobile SDK with Smartstore in Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, salesforce-ios-sdk

I have built a basic hybrid app in Ionic v2. Now I plan to add a local database to it to store and fetch it's menu items. For this I would like to use Salesforce Smartstore. But this is my first mobile app and I'm not sure how to go about it. I'm a salesforce developer, I went through the existing documentation but I am not able to follow that. Can someone list the steps I should perform to add and setup Salesforce mobile SDK with smart store to my existing ionic app?

Comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin

Comment: @David: Thanks for your reply. Will check that out for sure. Thanks again.